# Suppose that $f_{n} \to 0$ a.e. and $\int_{E} |f_{n}(x)-1|d\mu \to 1$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} |f_{n} - a|d\mu = 1-(1-|a|)\mu(E)$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having trouble with the following question:

Let $(E, \mathcal{E},\mu)$ be a finite measure space.

> Suppose that $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} |f_{n}(x)-1|d\mu =1$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} |f_{n} - a|d\mu = 1-(1-|a|)\mu(E)$

I don't have any good ideas to approach this, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What does $f\to 0$ a.e. mean?

Comment: @OliverDiaz That makes no sense. $f$ is a function, not a sequence of functions.

Comment: @zhw. The typo has been corrected. Things should make sense now.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so i am not realy good at real analysis so there definitely a possibility that i made some mistake but maybe this could help you.

first let $g_n=\left\lvert f_n-a \right\rvert -\lvert f_n-1 \rvert$
now since $f_n \to 0$ a.e  its quit easy to see that $g_n  \to  \lvert a \rvert -1$ a.e.
also notice that by the reverse triangle inequality $\lvert g_n \rvert \le \lvert 1-a \rvert$
so we can use the Dominated convergence theorem meaning
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_E g_nd\mu =\int_E \lim_{n \to \infty} g_nd\mu=\int_E \lvert a \rvert -1 = (\lvert a \rvert -1)\mu(E)$$
now we can finaly conclude that
$$1- (\lvert a \rvert -1)\mu(E)= 1-\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_E g_nd\mu=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_E \lvert f_n -1 \rvert d\mu-\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_E g_n d\mu\\=  \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_E \lvert f_n-1 \rvert-g_n d\mu=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_E \lvert f_n-a \rvert $$